# Fastest way to transfer image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've written a [nodejs module](https://github.com/Qualphey/node-linuxcam) to capture images from webcam (linux) and convert them to jpeg. Now I'm trying to transfer the data from server to client (browser) in the fastest possible way. So far I've tried to simply emit every image with socket.io, but I fear this is a really slow approach. Also I'm trying to use [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) module, hoping that it will gain some speed, but so far I found no way to implement it... What solutions could you suggest?

Comment: it will be only as fast as your connection. do you have one client for multiple waiting for that image?

Comment: One client one server